# Django query bases on greater date

Tags: django-models, django-queryset

I want to know how efficient this filter can be done with django queries. Essentially I have the followig two clases

```
class Act(models.Model):
    Date = models.DateTimeField()
    Doc = models.ForeignKey(Doc)
    ...

class Doc(models.Model):
    ...
```

so one Doc can have severals Acts, and for each Doc I want to get the act with the greater Date. I'm only interested in Acts objects.

For example, if a have

```
act1 = (Date=2021-01-01, Doc=doc1)
act2 = (Date=2021-01-02, Doc=doc1)
act3 = (Date=2021-01-03, Doc=doc2)
act4 = (Date=2021-01-04, Doc=doc2)
act5 = (Date=2021-01-05, Doc=doc2)
```

I want to get [act2, act5] (the Act with Doc=doc1 with the greater Date and the Act with Doc=doc2 with the greater Date).

My only solution is to make a for over Docs.

Thank you so much

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me *what* you want to do. Can you give some sample data and the expected output?

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with one or two queries: the first query will retrieve the latest `Act` per `Doc`, and then the second one will then retrieve the acts:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

last_acts = Doc.objects.annotate(
    latest_act=Subquery(
        Act.objects.filter(
            Doc_id=OuterRef('pk')
        ).values('pk').order_by('-Date')[:1]
    )
).values('latest_act')
```

and then we can retrieve the corresponding `Act`s:

```
Act.objects.filter(pk__in=last_acts)
```

depending on the database, it might be more efficient to first retrieve the primary keys, and *then* make an extra query:

```
Act.objects.filter(pk__in=list(last_acts))
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have a model a little difference from the question. How about if a change the line Doc = models.ForeignKey(Doc) by Doc = models.BigIntegerField()? So in this model the reference to the Doc table is made by this integer.

Comment: @DiegoSilvera: then it is `Doc=OuterRef('pk')` but it is a *very bad* idea not to use a `ForeignKey`. `ForeignKey`s will automatically create indexes, and guarantee referential integrity.